# HLSL Variable Returning Zero To MonoGame

Tags: xna, monogame, hlsl

To improve performance, I offloaded some CPU tasks onto the GPU with Effects. This is what my HLSL code looks like:

```
float angle;
extern float2 direction;

float4 PixelShaderFunction(float4 pos : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR0, float2 coords : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
{
    angle = atan2(direction.x, -direction.y);

    return float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

technique DefaultTechnique
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

In the Emitter class, I set the direction, apply the technique, and then retrieve the "angle" variable:

```
gpu.SetValue("direction", particles[i].Velocity);

for (int i = 0; i < effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes.Count; i++)
     effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[i].Apply();

particles[i].Angle = gpu.RetrieveFloat("angle");
```

This runs fine with no crashing. However, the "angle" value is always 0. My HLSL skills aren't great, but the code *looks* like it should work as expected.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you try changing the `angle` value to a *specific value*? If you successfully get that value back from the shader, then it's likely that you have an issue in the computation that you're trying to make ... as opposed to an issue with how the API is being used to fetch the value back out :)